# Changing the order of crossreferences in biblatex footnotes

Tags: cross-referencing, footnotes, biblatex-dw

I'm trying to use `biblatex-dw` and the `crossref` functionality to make my bibliography more structured and easier to edit. I'm using the `mvcollection`, `collection`, and `incollection` types for the inheritance/tree structure. My problem is that when I define things as in the MWE below, the footnote comes out wrong.

What I want to achieve -- but only for the archival document types -- is to organize the data into a hierarchy, starting with the most detailed (i.e. the specific document) and ending with the leaste detailed (i.e. the archive institution where the archive is situated):

document - volume - archive - archive institution

Therefore, the date would look strange at the end of the line as it refers to the document and not the archive institution. I think it looks much better if the data is clustered. But for normal references like books and articles, I agree the default biblatex ordering is great.

See image example below.

**Update**: I also tried this with `biblatex-chicago` and the same thing happens there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose-ibid,style=footnote-dw,autocite=footnote,idembibformat=dash,idemtracker=false,pageref=true,xref=true, date=iso8601]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@mvcollection{MA,
    title = {Museum archives},
}

@collection{ClockExhib,
    crossref = {MA},
    title = { Clocks Project},
}

@incollection{foo,
    crossref = {ClockExhib},
    author = {Committee},
    title = {Meeting notes},
    volume = 1,
    date = {1979-11-19},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{refs}

\begin{document}

This is a document.\autocites{foo}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the order of the details (and as a bonus also learn how to change the field separators...commas, dots, or whatever).

Any ideas would be much appreciated. 
By the way, I really want to stick to biblatex-dw.

Actual output of footer:
[image: ugly output]

Desired output:
[image: nicer output]

Comment: Have you had a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/15925 ?  I am not convinced that your desired output is helpful to the reader. The ordering `biblatex` provides seems more logical to me, with the possible exception of the placing of the `date` in this particular case.

Comment: Basically, what I want to achieve - but only for the archival document types - is to organize the data into a hierarchy, starting with the most detailed (i.e. what document) and ending with the leaste detailed (i.e. the archive institution where the archive is housed): document - volume - archive - archive institution. Therefore, the date would look strange at the end of the line as it refers to the document. I think it looks much better if the data is clustered. But for normal references like books and articles, I agree the default biblatex ordering is great.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thanks for the link on how to customize biblatex. I manage to solve this by editing standard-dw.bbx, the part which begins with "\DeclareBibliographyDriver{collection}{%" and moving the date section up. It's looking good now, but I'm sure it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: You can put that definition in your preamble, rather modifying the standard style file.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Ah, okay, I didn't know that. Thanks! :-) So unless someone else has something to add, I consider this solved.